# Question Related to the Qiskit Statevector_simulator, which returns the probability in a mixed form each time

Tags: quantum-state, ibm-q-experience

"""

```
from qiskit.providers import aer
from qiskit.circuit import QuantumCircuit,reset

def run_circuit(circuit:QuantumCircuit)
  print(circuit)
  simulator = aer.Aer.get_backend("statevector_simulator")
  result1 = simulator.run(circuit).result()
  statevector1 = result1.get_statevector(circuit)
  prob_vector1 = Statevector(statevector1).probabilities()
  print(prob_vector1)
  result2=simulator.run(circuit).result()
  statevector2 = result2.get_statevector(circuit)
  prob_vector2 = Statevector(statevector2).probabilities()
  print(prob_vector2)
```

"""
The code above is what I am using to run some simple circuit. See image of the circuit below.
[image: Image of Circuit I am running.]

As you can see from the print line after the circuit, the probability vector is mixed up for the same circuit when run twice. Does anyone know why this is happening? I am assuming it has something to do with the reset operation, as without it it works fine everytime. But is there a way to do the reset operation and not get this bug?

Thanks and Best Regards

AP

Edit with New Information:

So it seems that when you use the reset operation, rather than give you the new state vector, it causes the collapse of the state vector and gives full probability to a specific state. I have these images from the IBMQ lab that show what I am taking about. Does anyone know how to make it so that it gives the correct state vector and not the collapsed state?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset instruction is composed of a mid-circuit measurement followed by an X-gate conditioned on the outcome of the measurement<sup>[[1](https://docs.quantum-computing.ibm.com/build/backend_reset#conditional-reset)]</sup>. So, the collapse is inevitable due to this implicit measurement.

In your case, you will always get two state vectors, one for the case where the state after reset is $|00\rangle$, and the other for the case where the state is $|10\rangle$. Unless, of course, you prepared the state without non-unitary operations.

Answer (score 0):

In `run_circuit` function you are printing probabilities 2 times may be i.e it is happening you can refactor your code as follow:

```
def run_circuit(circuit:QuantumCircuit)
  print(circuit)
  simulator = aer.Aer.get_backend("statevector_simulator")
  result1 = simulator.run(circuit).result()
  statevector1 = result1.get_statevector(circuit)
  prob_vector1 = Statevector(statevector1).probabilities()
  return prob_vector1
```

Comment: Hey Raghav, my question was more so with regards to why, when the circuit is run twice do I get different state vectors for the same circuit. Should the state-vector not be the same, as none of the operators are changing? and does this change have something to do with non-unitary nature of the reset qubit that I am not understanding or is it the specific implementation of the statevector_simulator that is causing this issue.